# Arduino uploading to the wrong port

Tags: arduino-ide, uploading, mac-os

I purchased a half dozen fake Arduinos hoping to build a bunch of projects without paying a fortune. I have all the drivers installed, and the port shows up in the Arduino IDE. The problem is when I try and upload the code I get the following error:

> can't open device "/dev/cu.wch": No such file or directory

I played around a little and tried running:

```
sudo ln -s cu.wch\ ch341\ USB\=\>RS232\ 1a1220  cu.wch
```

After running this a new port shows up called `cu.wch`, and if I select that it works.

The issue is the Arduino's port is `cu.wch ch341 USB=>RS232 1a1220`, but for some reason the IDE is trying to write to `cu.wch`. By linking the folders I can fix this but since it is a hack every time I restart my computer I have to rerun the command. Is there a way I can either rename the Arduino port or permanently link the folder?

*I am using OSX 10.10 and Arduino IDE v1.6.3*

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the problem is the IDE not properly handling device names containing spaces. Consider your symlink a workaround rather than a hack - unless you want to repair the IDE itself.

Answer (score -1):

You must download the CH431 drivers to your computer and restart. This will solve your problem. Google these drivers, you should be able to find them. If not, let me know and I can send you a link to my drive.

Comment: Already did that. Please note as I mentioned I am using OSX 10.10.2 Yosemite. Before 10.10 (Mavericks) this solution would have worked, but the update seems to have broken this method. Please read my question carefully where I said "I have all the drivers installed".